# Remote Process configuration issue

Tags: robotframework, remote-server

I have problems with Remote process server and process configuration, I have a remote server started as:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from robotremoteserver import RobotRemoteServer
    RobotRemoteServer(Process(), *sys.argv[1:])
```

In the other side, I have the client, that seems to work fine, is imported with:

```
Library           Remote    http://192.168.1.25:4444    WITH NAME    RemoteKW
```

If I do a:

```
${id}=    RemoteKW.Start Process    echo    hello    world
${result}=    RemoteKW.Terminate Process    ${id}
${rc}    ${output}    ${stderr}=    RemoteKW.Get Process Result    ${id}    rc=true    stdout=true    stderr=true
Log    ${output}
```

everything is ok, it logs: "hello world", but when I try o redirect the stdout to a file, then it passes the redirection as argument instead as a configuration:

```
${id}=    RemoteKW.Start Process    echo    hello    world    stdout=tmp.txt
${result}=    RemoteKW.Terminate Process    ${id}
${rc}    ${output}    ${stderr}=    RemoteKW.Get Process Result    ${id}    rc=true    stdout=true    stderr=true
Log    ${output}
```

Then it doesn't work fine, the log is "hello world stdout=tmp.txt" and the tmp.txt file doesn't exists.
If I use the same sentences in local (changing "RemoteKW." by "Process.") it works fine, but in local...

Any idea about why in remote is not working fine?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This works as expected on my system. Are you using an old copy of the remote server? The method RobotRemoteServer.run_keyword should have an argument called kwargs. The behavior you see is what would be expected before keyword argument support was added to the remote server.

Comment: I tried it with robotframework 2.8.7 and 3.0 (both with python 2.7.11)

Comment: The remote server does not come with Robot Framework. Check the version of the server.

Comment: Ok, I found it, it seems you are right there isn't kwargs arguments in run_keyword, I will update to the last version and check it, thanks

Comment: finally, @ombre42 was right, I had an older version of robotremoteserver, I have updated it, and all works fine now